# How do I connect my OSX Cocoa Application with facebook?

Tags: cocoa, facebook, macos

I know that you can connect an iOS App with facebook using facebook connect, a library provided by facebook to get easy access to the facebook services.
Can someone explain me how I can connect a OSX Cocoa Application with facebook? I don't get it and all I can find is how to create Apps inside facebook but what I want is to access facebook to show new from my facebook friends in my application.

Is there a library or a documented way on how to do this?

Thank you very much

twickl

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't a library for OSX apps (at least, not an official one). You can always use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api) to grab content from Facebook.

If you decide to go this way, I think that you will need some script in order to [get an access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and have access to content inside your friends profiles.

Comment: Do you know any "unoffical" ones? :) A little tutorial on how to "call" the Graph API with Cocoa would be enough...